# Requesting a question to be re-opened because it is not opinion based

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons, reopen

I want the question *[Thoughts on neural networks "discovering" physical concepts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/564992/)* to be reopened.

I realize that there was a "what is your opinion..." line in it earlier. I have removed it. Please have a look at it in its current form and I hope you will agree that it admits concrete answers even though it is a soft question.

Again, I am requesting it to be reopened so that it can be answered by members here who are well-versed in the scientific method underlying physics.

Comment: This question's [reopen review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/307075) is still underway. It is not necessary to request reopening or closing specific questions on meta, that's what the review queues are for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not asking about how the Physics Stack Exchange site works.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I don't see how this is off-topic at all. It's essentially the same as asking why their question was closed, and meta is the appropriate place to ask such questions.

Comment: @BioPhysicist: I don't understand where else I can ask such questions. The site name is literally "meta". Do you have alternative suggestions to get feedback or just a very narrow view on how to use the site?

Comment: If you were asking about closure reasons then I think it would be fine. But all you are doing here is requesting that your question be reopened. You are not asking a question about the site here.

Comment: Undelete the question, it is unanswerable now.

Answer (score 8):

Even though you have eliminated an explicit reference to opinion, this does not change the fact that IMO the question is still opinion-based.  I can answer yes/no/I think so/I don’t think so without reference to any physical law or principle, and my answer would be just as good as anybody else’s.

Comment: appreciate the feedback. could you help me with any other references/sites/forums where i can clarify this kind of a question?